# Unhandled rejections in mocha tests from native code

Tags: node.js, debugging, promise, mocha.js

I am getting "unhandled rejection" messages in mocha tests but I am at lost what is the exact source of the problem since this happens asynchronously.

I know that I can add an event listener for the global unhandledRejection event like:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason)  {
     console.error(reason);
     process.exit(1);
});
```

but that doesn't really help, since the trace is then like follows:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/testfile.json'
    at Error (native)
  cause: 
   { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/testfile.json'
       at Error (native)
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/tmp/testfile.json' },
  isOperational: true,
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/tmp/testfile.json' }
```

The problem is the same with the node's inbuilt handler. No backtrace.

Apparently I don't get a proper backtrace because the rejection happens in the native fs module.
If I try to run just the test where this trace happens, it doesn't happen at all. It is probably because of a runaway promise that was set up somewhere "earlier". The specified /tmp/ path doesn't exist anywhere in the test code or the actual implementation code. The testfile.json does exist but not in that path.

I am running mocha 3.5.3 with node 6.5.0.

So the question then is: how to narrow down to find the problematic code?

Comment: *The specified /tmp/ path doesn't exist anywhere in the test code or the actual implementation code* - what about `testfile.json`?

Comment: That one does exist. Updating the question.

Comment: Check where it is used in code base and proceed from there. It's unknown where `/tmp/` could get from and this is possibly not important. What important is why wrong path was used. Could be because you rely on CWD by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One generic approach. Bisect the problem like:

1. move some test suite files to a separate directory so that they are not executed during the tests
2. Rerun mocha
3. Observe if the fail message persists
4. If yes, continue moving more files. If not, problematic file was one of the last moved ones.

Then continue bisecting the particular file that is causing the trouble. Comment away code until the problematic code is not executed.

Comment: This in fact helped me pinpoint the problem. The problem was that a few EventEmitter listener handlers were not stubbed for unit tests. This caused the error messages. Actual implementation listener code was running as a side effect during the later test suites. This code was of course using partially uninitialized variables.

Comment: I am accepting my own answer until someone comes up with a better method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it will help, but you can also get the `Promise` as an argument from the `unhandledRejection` listener to maybe get some more helpful output. Docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection)

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', p, 'reason:', reason);
  // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

Comment: In this case, it didn't help much. Basically I got more verbose trace but still without stack trace. I am still upvoting this because it might be helpful for somebody else.